# Calculate Number of ways to make the grid

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

We wish to tile a grid of size Nx2 with rectangles (dominoes) of 2x1 (in either orientation).For given N I need to find the number of different ways to tile the grid.

EXAMPLE : For N=1 answer is 1 and for N=2 answer is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if f(n) are the possible combinations in a n X 2 grid, I got the couples (n,f(n)): (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,5) (5,8), and it seems that f(n) are the so-called Fibonacci numbers. And it's really true!

In fact let's put the grid horizontally (you have n colums and 2 lines): the first rectangle can be put vertically or horizontally:

-if you put it vertically then you have a grid n-1 X 2, and all the possible combinations are f(n-1);

-if you put it horizontally, the second must be put horizontally under the first one; what you obtain is a grid n-2 X 2 to be filled, and the combinations are f(n-2).

So the number of total combinations of a n X 2 grid is the sum of the number of total combinations of a n-1 X 2 grid and the number of total combinations of a n-2 X 2 grid.
Now, since f(1) = 1, and f(2) = 2, it follows that f(n) = the n-th Fibonacci number, starting from 0 ... amazing what sort of link you can find between 2 so different areas of mathematics !